# In Angular is it possible to have code run before a Import Module is built?

Tags: javascript, angular

I need to setup my environment variables before an the import of a module occurs as this module's forRoot depends on these variables.

**app.module.ts**

```js
import { IssuerService } from './issuer.service';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule, APP_INITIALIZER } from '@angular/core';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { NgbModule } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';
import { PagesModule } from './pages/pages.module';
import { CustomCompModule } from './customcomp/customcomp.module';
import { ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { AppRoutingModule } from './/app-routing.module';
import {BrowserAnimationsModule} from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import { MatButtonModule } from '@angular/material/button';
import { MatCheckboxModule } from '@angular/material/checkbox';
import {MatTabsModule} from '@angular/material/tabs';
import { LoginComponent } from './pages/login/login.component';
import { LayoutComponent } from './pages/layout/layout.component';
import { HttpClientModule, HTTP_INTERCEPTORS } from '@angular/common/http';
import { AuthInterceptor } from './http.interceptor';
import {  MatIconModule,} from '@angular/material/icon';
import { MsalModule, MsalRedirectComponent, MsalGuard, MsalInterceptor } from '@azure/msal-angular'; // Import MsalInterceptor
import { InteractionType, PublicClientApplication } from '@azure/msal-browser';
const isIE = window.navigator.userAgent.indexOf('MSIE ') > -1 || window.navigator.userAgent.indexOf('Trident/') > -1;
import { MatToolbarModule } from '@angular/material/toolbar';
import { environment } from "./../environments/environment";
import { environmentLoader as environmentLoaderPromise } from './../environments/environmentLoader';

function initializeApp(): Promise<any> {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    // Do some asynchronous stuff
    environmentLoaderPromise.then(env => {
      environment.hosturl = env.hosturl;
      environment.clientid = env.clientid;
      environment.tenantid = env.tenantid;
      environment.redirecturi = env.redirecturi;
      environment.scopeserver = env.scopeserver;
      environment.scopeapi = env.scopeapi;
      environment.cid = env.cid;
      environment.production = env.production;
      resolve(1);
    })
    
  });
}


@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    LoginComponent,
    LayoutComponent,
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    PagesModule,
    CustomCompModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    NgbModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    MatButtonModule,
    MatCheckboxModule,
    MatTabsModule,
    MatIconModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    MatToolbarModule,
    MsalModule.forRoot(
       new PublicClientApplication({
      auth: {
        clientId: environment.clientid,
        authority: 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/' + environment.tenantid,
        redirectUri: environment.redirecturi
      },
      cache: {
        cacheLocation: 'localStorage',
        storeAuthStateInCookie: isIE,
      }
    }), {
      interactionType: InteractionType.Redirect,
      authRequest: {
        scopes: ['user.read']
        }
    }, {
      interactionType: InteractionType.Redirect, // MSAL Interceptor Configuration
      protectedResourceMap: new Map([ 
          [environment.scopeserver, [environment.scopeapi]]
      ])
    })
  ],
  providers: [   
    {
      provide: APP_INITIALIZER,
      useFactory: () => initializeApp,
      multi: true
     }, 
    {
    provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS,
    useClass: MsalInterceptor,
    multi: true
    },
    {
      provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS,
      useClass: AuthInterceptor,
      multi: true
    },
    MsalGuard,
    IssuerService
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent, MsalRedirectComponent] // MsalRedirectComponent bootstrapped here
})


export class AppModule {

 }
```

In my code you will see the module in question is MsalModule.

I added the Provider from the Angular Docs of APP_INITIALIZER that I thought was supposed to run and complete before anything else went forward.

However I can see that my env vars are not updating in time. They do load before AppComponent (I console.log them in AppComponent to test).

Any advice on how I can get this code to run before the MsalModule so that it is configured correctly?

Comment: Not sure, but have you tried the constructor of the AppModule?

Answer (score 0):

If you need to dynamically configure MSAL Angular (e.g. based on values returned from an API), you can use `platformBrowserDynamic`. `platformBrowserDyamic` is a platform factory, used to bootstrap the application, and is able to take in configuration options. platformBrowserDynamic should already be present when the Angular application is set up.
The following is an example of how to dynamically configure `@azure/msal-angular` with platformBrowserDynamic and a json file (or wrap in Promise):

```
import { enableProdMode } from '@angular/core';
import { platformBrowserDynamic } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';

import { AppModule } from './app/app.module';
import { environment } from './environments/environment';
import { MSAL_INSTANCE, MSAL_GUARD_CONFIG, MSAL_INTERCEPTOR_CONFIG } from '@azure/msal-angular';
import { PublicClientApplication, Configuration } from '@azure/msal-browser';

if (environment.production) {
  enableProdMode();
}

function loggerCallback(logLevel: LogLevel, message: string) {
  console.log("MSAL Angular: ", message);
}

fetch('/assets/configuration.json')
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(json => {
    platformBrowserDynamic([
      { provide: MSAL_INSTANCE, useValue: new PublicClientApplication({
        auth: json.msal.auth,
        cache: json.msal.cache,
        system: {
          loggerOptions: {
            loggerCallback,
            logLevel: LogLevel.Info,
            piiLoggingEnabled: false
          }
        }
      }) },
      { provide: MSAL_GUARD_CONFIG, useValue: {
        interactionType: json.guard.interactionType,
        authRequest: json.guard.authRequest,
        loginFailedRoute: json.guard.loginFailedRoute
      } as MsalGuardConfiguration },
      { provide: MSAL_INTERCEPTOR_CONFIG, useValue: {
        interactionType: json.interceptor.interactionType,
        protectedResourceMap: new Map(json.interceptor.protectedResourceMap)
      } as MsalInterceptorConfiguration },
    ])
      .bootstrapModule(AppModule)
      .catch(err => console.error(err));
  });
```